# How can I prevent bash from executing 'rm' when ' * ' is one of the arguments?

Tags: bash, rm

I wish to insure myself from accidentally using

`rm [argument_i] * [argument_j]`

i.e. it should always refuse to execute the command, when the asterisk character is separated by white space on both sides, no matter what else is before or after the asterisk.

Which command should I add to my `.bashrc` to enable such a check?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Related from [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better define an alias to rm, so whenever you execute rm, it won't be rm itself but your alias.

In this alias you can parse everything.

```
alias rm='/my/path/myrm.sh'
```

And this script can have all the parameters parsing that you want.

This alias should be put in .bashrc / .bash_profile, or even in /etc/profile if you want it to be applying to all user.

**Edit**
Following comments below, I added a wrapper that disables * interpreted as a list of all the files, and becomes just a string.

```
alias rm='set -f; /bin/sh /home/me/test/rm.sh'
```

The script could start like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if echo "$2" | grep '*' > /dev/null; then
    echo "asterisk!"
else
    echo "hi this is $var1 and $var2 and $var3"
fi
```

Test:

```
$ rm a * b
asterisk!
```

Comment: I don't think relying on an alias for `rm` is a good idea.  You'll get caught without the alias sometime, but you'll still be relying on its protection, and all hell will break loose.  It is better to learn to think "`rm` is dangerous; let me check my command line" than to rely on a crutch.

Comment: I agree with that, rm is quite dangerous and all of us have bad experiences with it :) Anyway, having an alias is the best solution I find for this case. Otherwise, you can also compile another `rm` but can be tough work.

Comment: I don't think this would help, as `*` is expanded by the shell prior to being sent as a parameter to your script or binary. So you won't find a `*` in the argument list of your script, but rather a list of all the files in the current directory.

Comment: But you could write a wrapper script that checks if all files of the current directory are passed in the arguments and warns/aborts, if they are there

Comment: Good to read all ideas. I took @BeniBela idea and got a couple of hints from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193658/check-if-a-string-contain-asterisk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701809/how-to-detect-using-of-wildcard-asterisk-as-parameter-for-shell-script . Now it should work with code in my answer.

Comment: @fedorqui: It's looking pretty good now. All you need to do is make sure that `set -f` doesn't stay active after the "rm" script is executed, otherwise it will apply to all subsequent shell commands. As I don't know how / if you can disable it once set, the best approach would be to make your script shebang: `#!/bin/bash -f` (instead of `#!/bin/sh`) and don't `set -f` in the alias itself.

Comment: Mmmm but if I set `set -f` inside the script, it will not be taken in consideration while calling it, so * will not be processed as a string. Then, I think the best way would be to write `unset -f` at the end of the script. What do you think?

Comment: `unset` is not a counterpart of `set`, it's only meant for discarding variables or functions. I think `set -f` will work fine inside the script, have you tested ?

Comment: It did not work to me. I tried both `#!/bin/bash -f` and `set -o noglob` but it is not working. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in a different question, using a DEBUG trap that checks BASH_COMMAND will do the trick:

```
check_for_wildcard_rm() {
  local rm_glob_re='^rm[[:space:]](.*[[:space:]])?[*]([[:space:]]|$)'
  if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ $rm_glob_re ]]; then
    echo "Suppressing rm with a bare *" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}
shopt -s extdebug
trap check_for_wildcard_rm DEBUG
```